# How can i use a code written to a text file as a cs class in my project?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a project that create a text file with a code of class inside and i use this project to update the text file every time i add or remove maps variables map,map1 .... but the rest of the code stay as it is.

I want to create from the text file a cs file so i can add it to my other project and use it as a class.
Just like i was doing right click on my project name Add > Class but not making new class and copy the code from the text file but using the text file as class.

This is the text file content now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace TowerDefense
{
    class Level
    {

int[,] map = new int[,]
{
 {1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,},
 {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,},
 {0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,},
 {0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,},
 {0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,},
 {0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,},
 {0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,},
 {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,},
};

int[,] map1 = new int[,]
{
 {0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,},
 {0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,},
 {0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,},
 {1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,},
 {0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,},
 {0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,},
 {0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
};

        private List<Texture2D> tileTextures = new List<Texture2D>();

        public void AddTexture(Texture2D texture)
        {
            tileTextures.Add(texture);
        }

        public int Width
        {
            get { return map.GetLength(1); }
        }
        public int Height
        {
            get { return map.GetLength(0); }
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch batch)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
                {
                    int textureIndex = map[y, x];
                    if (textureIndex == -1)
                        continue;

                    Texture2D texture = tileTextures[textureIndex];
                    batch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle(
                        x * 32, y * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rename from `file.txt` to `file.cs`. Adding it to your project will be harder though.

Comment: This sounds *a lot* like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you *actually* trying to accomplish?

Comment: It is definitely an XY problem. I'm not sure what you are trying to do, certainly not well enough to answer, but it sounds like **XML serialization** is your friend here.

Comment: What you're trying to modify is data, not code.  You'd probably be better off making a resource of the map data than generating a new class each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Rename your file with a .cs extension. This is automatically interpreted by the solution as a C# source file.
2. Add file to your project by editing the .csproj file programatically. You can find out details on how to do that here: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=adding%20file%20to%20.csproj&qscrl=1
3. Compile your project if you need to using CSharpCodeProvider.